# Trying to get a div w/ 100% height and overflow auto to work in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

So I've got this sidebar as a column in a table with a div inside that scrolls vertically. It works just fine in Chrome, but not in firefox. I've looked all over the net for solutions and none of the ones I tried worked. In firefox it ignores the 100% height and just pushes itself down, but I don't want that. I want it to scroll.

Here's what I have

HTML:

```
<body>
        <table class="wrapper">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" class="topbar">
                    Page title
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="sidebar">
                    <div class="listings">
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                        &nbsp;<br>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td><div id="map_canvas"></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" class="bottom">
                    hello
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video { margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; font-size: 100%; font: inherit; vertical-align: baseline; }
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section { display: block; }
body { line-height: 1; }
ol, ul { list-style: none; }
blockquote, q { quotes: none; }
blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after { content: ''; content: none; }
table { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; }

html, body {
    height:100%; /* needed for container min-height */
}

.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; 
}

.wrapper .topbar {
    background: #000;
    color: white;
    height: 35px;
}

.wrapper #map_canvas {
    background: white;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.wrapper .sidebar {
    width: 400px;
    /*height: 100%;*/
    background: white;
}

.listings {
    min-height: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: grey;
}

.wrapper .bottom {
    background: grey;
    height: 150px;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Oh, and I'm using this doctype: <!DOCTYPE HTML>

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I am experiencing the same problem.

Answer (score 6):

please put style="height:0;" in TD of Respective Div where you want scroll.

Comment: O.o . . . This answer should have 18 billion upvotes.  There are so many questions on Stack Overflow that this question duplicates, and this is the only one with the answer that just blew my mind.

Answer (score 0):

I bet it is due to tables. Using tables for shaping the whole page has not been used for a long and it is discouraged, it is semantically wrong.

Try to put your div's with `float:left` property, next to each other.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I'm using a table to maintain consistent heights in my columns. Using tables was a solution to another problem I had. I'd prefer to keep the table if at all possible.